# BackboneJS. How to add epoch chart to a view, when the view has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using BackboneJS along with RequireJS and I want to add a Epoch chart to a view.

What I have:

My view template is just:

```
<h1>Charts</h1>
<div id="gaugeChart" class="epoch gauge-small"></div>
```

My router

```
showChart: function(){
  $('#page-wrapper').html(new ChartsView().el);
}
```

My View

```
/*global define*/
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'handlebars',
  'd3',
  'epoch',
  'text!templates/Charts.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, d3, epoch, templateSource) {
  var ChartsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile(templateSource),

    events: {
      'click #gaugeChart': 'hasRendered'
    },

    initialize: function() {
      this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.append(this.template());
      return this;
    },

    hasRendered: function() {
      $('#gaugeChart').epoch({
        type: 'time.gauge',
        domain: [1, 100],
        format: function(v) {
          return v.toFixed(0);
        },
        value: 1
      });

    }
  });
  return ChartsView;
});
```

In the Backbone view above I have a click event on the `#gaugeChart` element and this approach works but how would I trigger a load event such that when the view has loaded I can call a JavaScript function to add the epoch chart.
I tried to trigger the `hasRendered` function once the render function had completed but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to defer the rendering of your chart by using a timeout so that it executes after the render function completes. For example

```
render: function() {
      this.$el.append(this.template());

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#gaugeChart').epoch({
             type: 'time.gauge',
             domain: [1, 100],
             format: function(v) {
               return v.toFixed(0);
              },
          value: 1
        });
      },0);

      return this;
    },
```

Alternatively another approach you can take is to have your router either call some method of your view to render Epoch chart after it attaches your el to the DOM or to to trigger an event which your view will use to render the chart.

For example

```
showChart: function(){
     var chartView = new ChartsView();
    $('#page-wrapper').html(chartView .el);

  //render chart directly
   chartView.renderChart(); //this assumes there is a "renderChart" method in your view
   //or trigger some event for view to respond to
  //chartView.trigger('atachedToDom'); //with your view subscribing to this event
}
```

Comment: The second approach is the way that I have done it at the moment but are there any better approaches should I be structuring my view or router differently? Thanks